# What should I use instead of AdIconView in Facebook Audience Network SDK version 5.2.1?

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I'm updating facebook audience network sdk, and using AdIconView.
but AdIconView is deprecated in Facebook Audience Network SDK version 5.2.1.
What should I use instead of AdIconView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use MediaView, according to their doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reference/android/com/facebook/ads/adiconview.html/?version=v5.3.0